# How to bind url parameters to callback function in express/node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I have callback function which takes 4 parameters like

```
function findFriend(req, res, name, year) {
// here I have tried to read

}
```

and I want to bind to url like

```
app.get('/api/name/:name/year/:year/student', students.findFriend);
```

and I expect to bind name to name and year to year but it is undefined. I also have tried to read paramters as req.params.name and req.params.year (also req.query.name and req.query.year) but it is always undefined. How to bind url parameters to callback function ?

Answer (score 3):

```
app.get('/api/name/:name/year/:year/student', function(req, res) {
  students.findFriend(req, res, req.params.name, req.params.year)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The values for `name` and `year` will come inside the `req.params.name` and `req.params.year` respectively.

Express does not know how to pass them as individual parameters to your function, but you can either (1) handle them inside your `students.findFriend` function or (2) define a wrapper function that will extract them from the `req.params` object and pass them down.